# Dataframe merge but keep categories

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 frames, 1 has continent data, the other metals-group data.

```
    continents
year  africa  asia
1996    2       3
1997    5       6

    metal-groups
year  ferrous  non-ferrous
1996    2       3
1997    5       6
```

I need to merge them on 'year', and try keep the categories associated with the columns of the final frame (i.e. continents and metal-groups).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Comment: @jezrael - if I execute your code, it doesn't add the categories (continents and metals-group) into the final dataframe. (The original dataframes don't have the category information in them to begin with - I guess this is the problem)

Comment: Can yu add output from your code to question? Also what is `print (df1.columns)` and `print (df2.columns)` ?

Comment: `print(df1.columns)`
Index(['Year', 'Iron and Ferro-Alloy Metals', 'Non-Ferrous Metals',
       'Precious Metals', 'Industrial Minerals', 'Mineral Fuels'],
      dtype='object')    `print(df2.columns)`
Index(['Year', 'Africa', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Latin America', 'North America',
       'Oceania'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Problem is you need `MultiIndex` in columns, how are created `df1, df2` ?

Comment: df1 and df2 are 2 different sheets from a .xls file that have been imported as df's. The name of the sheet describes the category.